# MVC areas and "404 resource not found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've inherited a broken MVC app from a programmer who left the company before I joined.  The previous programmer, in his last act here, reorganized the app into Areas (as shown in the attached Solution Explorer snapshot).  I'm pulling my hair out over what I am sure is a simple thing, but as I am new to MVC it is, at the moment, a huge thing:

Many of the links generated by the markup @Html.ActionLink() are working properly, but some are failing with a "404 resource cannot be found [...]" error.

Here is an example of a link that fails:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload Documents", "BlankPageTest", new { controller = "DocumentUpload", area = "Documents" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

... and here is a link that works:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Questions", "ChangeQuestions", new { controller = "Account", area = "UserAccount" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

Both of these links are in the markup for the View "MyAccount.cshtml", which lives in the area "UserAccount".  The only functional difference I can see between the link that fails and the one that works is that resource for the working link (ChangeQuestions.cshtml) LIVES IN THE SAME AREA as the view (MyAccount.cshtml).  However, since both the controller and area are parameters for Html.ActionLink(), I don't see how MVC would be getting confused.

The full URL given in the "404 resource not found" message is:

```
/CROMERR.Website/Documents/DocumentUpload/BlankPageTest
```

I have a method in the controller for the targeted URL named "DocumentUpload"... cannot find any more obvious things to try so thought I'd ask someone more knowledgeable.  Any and all help appreciated.

[image]

`DocumentAreaRegistration` contains the code:

```
public override string AreaName 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return "Documents"; 
    } 

} 

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{ 
    context.MapRoute( 
        "Documents_default", 
        "Documents/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Comment: What is in `DocumentsAreaRegistration` and is it being called form anywhere?

Comment: DavidG, DocumentAreaRegistration contains the code below.  The RegisterArea() method has zero references according to Visual Studio.


        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Documents";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Documents_default",
                "Documents/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: Yikes.  No ability to format code in the replies DavidG.  My apologies for the spaghetti.  There's one method in the file you pointed out but it isn't called from anywhere...

Comment: That's why we edit questions rather than posting code in comments. I've added the code in for you. Does `DocumentAreaRegistration` inherit from `AreaRegistration? In your `Application_Start` are you calling `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`? And finally, how about you adding `namespaces: new string[] { "Yournamespace.Areas.Controllers" }` to the `RegisterArea`from the method you posted?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions DavidG.  (1) Yes, DocumentAreaRegistration inherits from AreaRegistration.  (2) Application_Start in Global.asax calls AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas().

As for (3), I confess I'm a little confused.  Where would I add this?  And, more importantly, my impression of adding Areas in an MVC project by right-clicking and "add | area" was that this wireup was all done behind the scenes.  Is this not the case?  I understand if we're just verifying here that the wireup was done properly.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: This seems to be more of a problem in my (the previous programmer's?) understanding of areas and how to specify them. 

I've tried adding  new area/controller/view named "DocumentUploaderNew", "FileUploadContoler", "FileUploader", respectively, and the using Html.ActionLink() with [...]"FileUploader", new { controller = "FileUpload", area = "DocumentUploaderNew" }[...]  

The error I'm getting is"/CROMERR.Website/DocumentUploaderNew/FileUpload/FileUploader"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from a previous question that you asked, your issue is having your view in the wrong location which is causing the 404 error.

From the `DocumentUpload` controller, you are trying to return a view `BlankTestPage.cshtml`.  However, when viewing your screenshots, the `BlankTestPage.cshtml` view is actually located in the `Views/Documents` folder.  By default, MVC will only look in the folders `Views/ControllerName` (where controller name is the name of the controller trying to return the view) and `Views/Shared`.

If you need to reference `BlankTestPage.cshtml` from multiple controllers, place it in the Shared folder.  Else, you need to move that view from the Documents View folder into the DocumentUpload view folder (the empty one in your screenshot).